# Effect of a linear transformation on the perimeter of a shape

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

let assume $A: R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ is a linear transformation. (A is $2 \times 2$ matrix)

We know that the area of a shape's image is $ |det(A)| * S$, which $S$ is our original shape's area.

And my question is that what about the perimeter? Is there any relation between the original shape's perimeter and its image's perimeter?

I tried some examples, but I could not find a general relation!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perimeter of the image of a shape can be arbitrary large **even with a matrix with determinant $1$**.

Take for example the image of unit square $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)$ by transvection with matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&m\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

which is the parallelogram $(0,0),(0,1),(m+1,1),(m,1)$ with arbitrary large perimeter:

$$2+2 \sqrt{1+m^2}$$

[image]

*Fig. 1: The case $m=5$.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no general relation, though an interesting example you might want to learn about considers graph of $y=k*\sin(x)$ for a constant $k$ - this relates to the literature on Elliptic Integrals.

However, if $|\lambda_{min}| \le |\lambda_{max}|$ are the (absolute values of the) minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $A$ (assuming all of the eigenvalues are real so that the arc-length of $AS$ is defined) respectively, then we do have the bound

$|\lambda_{min}|\text{length}(S) \le \text{length}(AS) \le |\lambda_{max}|\text{length}(S)$. This holds for any-sized square matrices, not just 2 by 2.

Comment: Interesting fact! Does this property only hold for this curve? Can't we find such boundaries for other curves or shapes?

Comment: The inequality holds for any shape S. Surely for some curves there will be nice closed form expressions, but for the vast majority of examples there won't be. The exception is when the matrix $A$ is a multiple of the identity matrix - $A = cI$. Then of course the arc length increases by a factor of $|c|$.